# Run manage.py from AWS EB Linux instance

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

How to run `manage.py` from AWS EB (Elastic Beanstalk) Linux instance?

If I run it from '/opt/python/current/app', it shows the below exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I think it's related with virtualenv. Any hints?

Comment: You don't have django available for python interpreter used. Search the docs for more info about where the dependencies are installed. Are you sure they're installed at all?

Comment: Yes. it's AWS EB Python 2.7 environment with Django 1.5.5 installed. In fact, Django web application itself running well and I can see it from browser. But, I want to run custom command from Linux shell through SSH. In this case, I can see the error like the above.

Comment: Try to figure out the HTTP server does initialize the environments/setup paths then.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

How to run manage.py from AWS Elastic Beanstalk AMI.

- SSH login to Linux (`eb ssh`)

  - (optional may need to run `sudo su -` to have proper permissions)
- `source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate`
- `source /opt/python/current/env`
- `cd /opt/python/current/app`
- `python manage.py <commands>`

Or, you can run command as like the below:

- `cd /opt/python/current/app`
- `/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python manage.py <command>`

Comment: Even more compact: `/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py <command>`

Comment: It gives Permission denied

Comment: @RoNiT, you can use "sudo su -" to get root access, then you'll have the permission.

Comment: This is not the best answer. The whole point of EB is to automate deployment and not have to SSH into a machine.

Comment: @brandonjschwartz - its very common with django systems to use the manage.py shell command to interrogate data using the ORM rather than raw SQL, when its to do with data rather than changes to the filesystem this is completely fine

Comment: This is unfortunately no longer valid response in the new Python3.7 and Amazon Linux 2 platform.

Answer (score 17):

With the new version of Python paths seem to have changed.

- The app is in /var/app/current
- The virtual environment is in /var/app/venv/[KEY]

So the instructions are:

1. SSH to the machine using `eb shh`
2. Check the path of your environment with ls `/var/app/venv/`. The only folder should be the `[KEY]` for the next step
3. Activate the environment with `source /var/app/venv/[KEY]/bin/activate`
4. Execute the command `python3 /var/app/current/manage.py <command>`

Of course Amazon can change it anytime.

Comment: Wow - why was this so hard to find - thanks very much!

Comment: can you please clarify what [KEY] is above? it's not clear to me...

Comment: @m.arthur As described above KEY is the name of the only folder in /var/app/vent/

Comment: You can replace the [key] with * and this works

Answer (score 4):

As of February 2022 the solution is as follows:

```
$ eb ssh
$ sudo su -
$ export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
$ source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
$ python3 /var/app/current/manage.py <command name>
```

$ export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs) is needed to import your environment variables if you have a database connection (most likely you will)

Comment: This is confirmed working as of TODAY; can we go a step further? ``PSQL`` does not seem to work..

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

This answer assumes you have installed [EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html). Follow these steps:

1. Connect to your running instance using ssh.

```
eb ssh <environment-name>
```

2. Once you are inside your environment, load the environment variables (this is important for database configuration)

```
. /opt/python/current/env
```

If you wish you can see the environment variables using `printenv`.

3. Activate your virtual environment

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
```

4. Navigate to your project directory (this will depend on your latest deployment, so use the number of your latest deployment instead of `XX`)

```
cd /opt/python/bundle/XX/app/
```

5. Run the command you wish:

```
python manage.py <command_name>
```

### Running example

Asumming that your environment name is `my-env`, your latest deployment number is `13`, and you want to run the `shell` command:

```
eb ssh my-env # 1
. /opt/python/current/env # 2
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate # 3
cd /opt/python/bundle/13/app/ # 4
python manage.py shell # 5
```

Comment: Hey this doesnt seem to be working for me  after ssh - ". /opt/python/current/env" doesnt exists for me. Infact even opt/python doesnt. Please help!