# Install Scipy and Django on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, import, scipy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070161/2521204 to activate the virtual environment created by Elastic Beanstalk and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28116352/2521204 to install Numpy and Scipy on a "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Python 3.4."
In order to test the installation, I use the following:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and inside the Djnago Shell, I use the following:

```
import numpy
import scipy
```

I do not receive any error message here. However, when I call

```
from scipy import stats
```

in my views.py, it returns the following error message:

```
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Consider using a docker based setup as that gives you more control of the OS packages That you will need

Comment: @dkarchmer, Do you have any specific docker in mind that can solve this specific issue?

Comment: I didn't like any of the others, so I created my own: `tedder42/python3-scipy-cron`. Feel free to use that, or use it as a base for yours.

Comment: I also have my own, but used for ffmpeg as well, but you can reverse engineer it and create your own: https://github.com/ampervue/docker-ffmpeg-moviepy/blob/master/Dockerfile