# Create Django Super User in Elastic Beanstalk Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create a superuser for my app in Django. It's easy in localhost. However, I can't figure out how to do it in Elastic Beanstalk.

The methods I've tried are [aws guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) and [realpython](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) . However, none seems to work. My database is posgresql and it's connected to my application. However no superuser is being created through migrations.

How is it supposed to work?

Comment: What do you mean, "created through migrations"? Neither of those tutorials propose creating a superuser via migrations.

Comment: was the user i've created locally supposed to transfer to the beanstalk database automatically? i'm confused here.

Comment: No. The realpython tutorial suggests creating a specific management command to create the user (of course, you should immediately change the password via the admin site).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a superuser using the regular 'python manage.py createsuperuser' command from one of the EC2 instances running your application, following the instructions at [Run manage.py from AWS EB Linux instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997343/run-manage-py-from-aws-eb-linux-instance)

Notice that in order to be able to SSH into an instance, you need to provide a key-pair while creating your EB environment.