# Run Django manage.py shell commands on elastic beanstalk on AL2

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2, makemigrations

I have my Django service up and running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (on Amazon Linux 2). `eb deploy` works perfectly. But I would like to run some functions from shell of Django on by eb or maybe perform migrations on my DB.

I am unable to find my package after I `eb ssh <environment-name>` so cant find the `manage.py` file.

Related question - [Run manage.py from AWS EB Linux instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997343/run-manage-py-from-aws-eb-linux-instance)

I believe it might be outdated ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

##### Change to the current app directory

`cd /var/app/current/`

##### Change to the staging app directory (only exists after a failed eb deploy)

`cd /var/app/staging/`

##### Activate the virtual env

`source $(find /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate)`

##### Load your environment variables

`export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)`

##### Now you can run management commands

`python manage.py shell`

Comment: there does not seem to be any need to change to the staging directory

Comment: AWS post about [accessing environment variables on AL2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-linux2/)

Comment: An alternative way to load the environment properties is to use [get-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html), for example: `export $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment | sed -r 's/: /=/' | xargs)` This does not require `sudo`, so it may be useful in some cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't execute this command ```export $(sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)``` And it was taking up my local environment variables. Saved me a lot of hours

Comment: On Amazon Linux 2 it may be necessary (for example, to have permission to write to log files) to become the `webapp` user first: `sudo su -l - webapp`

Comment: execute this after connecting to running instance using `eb ssh <environment-name>`. Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997343/run-manage-py-from-aws-eb-linux-instance)